# Registering a custom MIME::Type in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As per my need I'm trying to register a custom MIME::Type as follows (including **text/plain**)

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :my_json, %w( text/plain text/x-json application/jsonrequest )
```

But when I run following command in rails console

```
Mime::MY_JSON
```

It gives output

```
#<Mime::Type:0x1739e5b0 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:my_json, @string="application/json">
```

Here, @synonyms is empty array.

But, I want the output like `Mime::JSON`  =>  `#<Mime::Type:0x53231d8 @synonyms=["text/x-json", "application/jsonrequest"], @symbol=:json, @string="application/json">`

So that I can use it like:

```
render :my_json => SomeJSON
```

What needs to done?

**EDIT**

This is my entry in config/initializers

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :my_json, %w( text/plain text/x-json application/jsonrequest )
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this a pretty old question, an answer for `Rails 6` would be as follows -

- To register a custom mime type you should use `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`. Add a similar line there as below (as mentioned in [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads)) -

```rb
Mime::Type.register 'application/json', :my_json, %w( text/plain text/x-json application/jsonrequest )
```

> Please not here, if you follow the [Mime::Type](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html) API, the `extension_synonyms` param consists of symbols not strings.

- To fetch mime type with `string` name, use -

```rb
Mime::Type.lookup('application/json')
```

- To fetch mime type with `symbol` name, use -

```rb
Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:my_json)
```

Answer (score -3):

As per [paulasmuth](http://paulasmuth.com/blog/rails_custom_mime_types/), `Custom MIME` type can also be done in the controller. Just call this `register` method from your controller.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :my_json, %w( text/plain text/x-json application/jsonrequest )
```

Your mime type can be used in the respond_to block now:

```
respond_to do
 format :your_mime_type do 
  #do something
 end
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What difference does it make to define MIME type in controller instead of initializer.

Comment: I just add another way of getting the solution done :)